# ¿Como organizar versiones de bootstrap MVC C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

estoy usando una plantilla que depende de bootstrap 4 y quiero usar plug in 
[Bootstrap Table MVC](https://github.com/simonray/bootstrap-table.mvc)
pero ocupa una version inferior de bootstrap
no cargar correctamente los iconos galphicons

entonces como hago para que pueda cargar los iconos o usar las dos versiones?

Comment: usar 2 versiones de un mismo framework CSS es una muy mala idea... sugerencia: Trabaja con la versión 3.

Comment: Elimina todas las versiones que no necesites y solo quedate con la que si  vayas a utilizar y problema resuelto.

Comment: pero las dos las ocupo como son diferentes codigos no funcionan bien si le cambias la version que usaron

Comment: en si son dos codigos que no hice yo y me toco fusionar pero usaron dos versiones diferentes framework